# SQL Server using a local temp table in a stored procedure created in a different stored procedure

Tags: sql-server

I have inherited a database that contains a lot of stored procedures that create a local temporary table, calls a procedure that uses the temp table, and then deletes the temp table. Like this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE procSelectFromTable
    AS
    BEGIN
        SELECT *
    FROM #myTable
END;
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE procMakeTable
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT 1 AS [ID]
        ,'NestedProcedure' AS [Message]
    INTO #myTable;

    EXEC procSelectFromTable

    DROP TABLE #myTable;
END;
GO

EXEC procMakeTable;
GO

--Clean up
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#myTable') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE #myTable;

DROP PROCEDURE procMakeTable;

DROP PROCEDURE procSelectFromTable
```

I have not seen procedures written in this manner before. Is it safe for me to assume this is ok because the nested procedure will always be called in the same spid and will always be able to access the temp table?

Comment: Discussed in greater detail by Erland [here](http://www.sommarskog.se/share_data.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the nested procedure will have access to the local temp table. This was common use before the introduction of table-valued parameters or when the procedures exist in different databases in the same instance. The procedures are tightly coupled and might be a problem to test the 'child' procedure, but it has the advantage that it can be called from multiple procedures.